# FTP over LAN without Internet Access

Tags: networking, ethernet, router

This last days I had been using a FTP Server (Running on my PC), and I pointed some IP Cameras to it (to send snapshots every second).

I have this:

ISP -> ADSL MODEM + ROUTER -> Switch -> PC, Camera 1, Camera 2, Camera 3, Camera N

And everything work fine. But, when I remove the MODEM <-> SWITCH Ethernet cable, all cameras became unable to connect to the FTP, but if I try from another PC on the same network I can ping and connect to the FTP Server.

When I unplug the ethernet cable from the MODEM, I restart every device on my isolated network (both cameras and PC's)

I tried different switches and routers but still got the same behavior. I know there is some Network Knowledge missing but I can't figure it out what is.

I'm using ubuntu 16.04 with proftpd as FTP Server

Comment: Is the PC trying to connect to the cameras, or are they trying to connect to the PC? If the latter then it *might* me that they are trying to do a DNS lookup (using the router as a DNS server) and this is failing. replacing the switch by a hub and running a tool such as wireshark would enable you to see more about what is happening.

Comment: Yes, all cameras are trying to connect to the PC. I will try to see what is happening using wireshark, and update the question. Thanks.

Comment: The Modem/Router probably runs DHCP, and the Camera's don't get an IP address without it. If you want a private LAN without internet connection, it still needs a DHCP server (and possibly a DNS server).

Comment: The TP-Link router has enabled the DHCP Server and every device get an IP address. I can connect to the camera IP and see the video, and change configurations without a problem. The only thing that stop working is the FTP connection (camera to PC)